# Eclipse: The color used for text in a content assist popup

Tags: eclipse

I have problem with colour used for the background of a content assist popup. I try to change in the menu *Window/Preferences/General/Appearance/Color and fonts* -> these items without effect:

- Content Assist background colour
- Content Assist foreground colour

[image]

I can not get to the right one item had a half a day. **Please help**.

Comment: The answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571850/eclipse-change-popup-text-background-color-when-hovering-the-mouse-on-a-keyword.
Very stupid rule on this website that sets threshold on the minimum of characters in the answer forces me to put this meaningless sentence here.

Answer (score 1):

eclipse -> preference -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts

1. Code assist

   Basic > Content Assist background color    -> change
   Basic > Content Assist foreground color    -> change
2. java doc

   Java  > Javadoc background ( overrides default: information background color) -> change